# How to dynamically create a struct with one less property?

Tags: go, reflection

Is there a way to copy a generic struct (i.e. a struct whose property names are unknown) and skip a single, known property?

Here is what I know:

- The parameter to my function--I will call the parameter `myData`-- is of type `interface{}`.
- `myData` is a struct.
- `myData` has a known property `path`.
- `myData` has anywhere from 0 to 6 or so other properties, none of which are known a priori.
- Once I remove that `path` property, then the “leftover” is one of say 30 possible struct types.

So I want to strip `path` out of `myData` (or more accurately make a copy that omits `path`) so that various bits of generated code that try to coerce the struct to one of its possible types will be able to succeed.

I have found examples of copying a struct by reflection, but they typically create an empty struct *of the same underlying type*, then fill it in. So is it even possible to delete a property as I have outlined...?

Comment: What about `reflect.StructOf`? Creates a new struct type from a list of fields.

Comment: Something like this maybe? https://play.golang.org/p/j4MYSq5GklS

Comment: @mkopriva Thank you for that code! I think that will do what I need so I will wire it up and see if there are any other assumptions that I may have overlooked in my problem statement.

Comment: No problem, just make sure before you call `reflect.Value.Convert` to use `reflect.Value.Type().ConvertibleTo`... because if that returns false `Convert` panics.

Comment: first of all is a struct the right construct for your task? you must have those 30 possible structs types defined somewhere anyway, then you can define another 30 with that one extra field. Seems like a good case for code generation...

Comment: Post your code as an answer @mkopriva and I can give you the credit for it. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`reflect.StructOf`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StructOf) to dynamically create structs from a list of fields.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type A struct {
    Foo string
    Bar int
    Baz bool // to be skipped
}

type B struct {
    Foo string
    Bar int
}

func main() {
    av := reflect.ValueOf(A{"hello", 123, true})

    fields := make([]reflect.StructField, 0)
    values := make([]reflect.Value, 0)
    for i := 0; i < av.NumField(); i++ {
        f := av.Type().Field(i)
        if f.Name != "Baz" {
            fields = append(fields, f)
            values = append(values, av.Field(i))
        }
    }

    typ := reflect.StructOf(fields)
    val := reflect.New(typ).Elem()
    for i := 0; i < len(fields); i++ {
        val.Field(i).Set(values[i])
    }

    btyp := reflect.TypeOf(B{})
    bval := val.Convert(btyp)

    b, ok := bval.Interface().(B)
    fmt.Println(b, ok)
}
```