# How to create struct dynamically in Golang by reading settings file?

Tags: go, reflection

I would like to create structs by reading *.yaml file and struct name, property names and their types should be set in settings file.

```
PERIOD: 1y
KEYSPACE: Lana
Tables:
  User:
    - UserId UUID
    - Gender String
    - Age Integer
    - Likes String
    - Income Integer
    - Children Integer
```

I know I should use reflection, should I? :-).

Comment: Why don't you just use a [yaml parser](https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml)?

Comment: Use `map[string]interface{}` for passing unknown values.

Comment: Do you want to generate Go code?

Comment: Thank you, Flimzy. I am using viper and cobra - I can easily read settings. Now I have several variables: nameOfStruct like a string, fields and now I would like to create a struct with name User, which has those props and their types. Then I would like to generate Cassandra tables.

Comment: Sorry, Himanshu - can you give me more details?

Comment: Peter, not  necessarily - just would like to create structs dynamically and then generate Cassandra tables with <https://github.com/kristoiv/gocqltable>

Comment: @Svitlana: Are you looking for something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49704604/965900

Comment: @mkopriva Yes, seems the answer I was looking for, I hope I can reach the goal I set. I need to learn more about reflection :-), I was taught by Rob Pike that "You never need reflection, if you do - you are doing something wrong" :-)

Comment: @Svitlana those are general rules, not dogma. The std lib uses reflect, e.g. the json std lib is relying heavily on reflect. Keep in mind, with reflect the most you can do is create anonymous structs, i.e. you actually cannot give the struct a name, and therefore you also cannot refer to the struct by name anywhere in your program. Something like this is possible though https://play.golang.org/p/PduDUz38gVO .

Comment: @mkopriva Thank you, mkpriva!!! I will try to wrap my head around and hope to get deep understanding of reflect. It seems for now that hardcoding is not a big deal for me at this moment :-). I am very grateful for your detailed anwers. I will readThemAll :-). Have the great day!

Comment: Have you consider code generation ?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use a `map[string]interface{}`?

```
func Load(filename string) (map[string]interface{}, error) {
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filename)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("error reading file, %s", err.Error())
    }
    var result map[string]interface{}
    err := yaml.Unmarshal(data, result)

    return result, err
}
```